# Angular JS - listen or bind $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to listen/bind an event every time there's an $http request and also after it receives a response?

Actually I've done it manually by providing my own events and listeners, but I'm just curious if there's already a listener in Angular JS for this?

The reason why I wanted to do this is that, every time my application sends/execute an $http request I wanted to show my loading screen to indicate that the app is retrieving data then hide it after it receives a response.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to do this

```
var httpinterceptor = function ($q, $location) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            //show your loading message
            console.log(config);
            return config;
        },

        response: function (result) {
            //hide your loading message
            console.log('Repos:', result);
            return result;
        },

        responseError: function (rejection) {
            //hide your loading message
            console.log('Failed with', rejection);
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
};

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(httpinterceptor);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w84q2Lzb/)

Answer (score 1):

there is already a module on it which you can use and modify it according to your required check this  [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Angular Loading Bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/).  It automates the loading bar's progress, by using angular interceptors. Multiple requests within the same time period get bundled together such that each response increments the progress bar by the appropriate amount.

```
    app.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false; // second boot loader, you can show or hide
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true; // main loader
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.latencyThreshold = 200; // delay
    }])
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, will look in to this.