# AngularJS: Refreshing service result

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I have a service getting *items* by `$http`. In the controller I share this data with the view. It works, but when I delete or add new items by `$http`, I cannot get my list to stay up to date.

I created a `refresh()` function, that I call every time I add or delete an item, but the *refresh applies only from time to time*. And not on every action though the function is always duly called and executed.

How should I proceed to get my items refreshed on every action?

**Function**:

```
refresh = function() {
    itemsService.getItems().then(function(d) {
        $scope.items= d;
      });
}
```

**Service**:

```
app.factory('itemsService', function($http) {

    var itemsService = {
        getItems: function() {
            return $http.get('items.json')
                .then(
                    function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }
                );
        }
    };

    return itemsService;
});
```

I have also read about `$watch()` and tried to make it work in this case, but it does not seem to make any difference:

```
$scope.$watch('itemsService.getItems()', function(d) {
    $scope.items = d;
}, true);
```

Comment: What do you mean that "the refresh applies only from time to time"? As in, only sometimes does it actually refresh the data on the screen?

Comment: One piece of suggestion would be to avoid making two requests when adding or deleting data. You can keep the track of data that is requested to be added or deleted and when the success occurs, push that data to the array of data.

Comment: @shieldstroy Exactly, the data on the screen is often refreshed but not always, but if I put a `console.log()` in my function, I can see that it is always executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for 
[Angular JS - listen or bind $http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803946/angular-js-listen-or-bind-http-request)

You can just call your function when the request ends.

You can use an interceptor to do this

```
var httpinterceptor = function ($q, $location) {
return {
    request: function (config) {
        //show your loading message
        console.log(config);
        return config;
    },

    response: function (result) {
        //hide your loading message
        console.log('Repos:', result);
        return result;
    },

    responseError: function (rejection) {
        //hide your loading message
        console.log('Failed with', rejection);
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
}
```

};

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(httpinterceptor);
```

});